# Firebase does not return JSON array field

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

Something strange for me going on in Firestore database. I save there multiple documents as a JSON that include arrays. I can see this array in document at Firestore console but when I'am trying to retrieve the document is return all fields expect the array field:

here is screenshot of document with array:

[image]

but in go language based app the document received without this field. How come ?

the code:

```
    credentials, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(srv.Ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get default credentials: %w", err)
    }

    opt = option.WithCredentials(credentials)

    firebaseConfig := &firebase.Config{
        ProjectID: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    }

    app, err := firebase.NewApp(srv.Ctx, firebaseConfig, opt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not initialize token source. %w", err)
    }

    client, err := app.Firestore(srv.Ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Cold not open connection to Firestore. %w", err)
    }


    collection := client.Collection(RELEASES_COLLECTION_NAME).
        Where("BranchName", "==", branch).
        Where("ProductName", "==", productName).
        OrderBy("PublishedAtSortedUTC", firestore.Desc).
        Limit(count).
        Documents(ctx)

    for {
        doc, err := collection.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            return result, nil
        } else {
            return nil, err
        }

        if doc != nil {

            m := doc.Data()
            fmt.Println(m)
...
...
...
```

and the results is:

[image]

all other fields do exist but not the array field... What I can do in this case ?

When I query for this document by REST api the json returned show that this array does exist:

```json
   ...
   ...
    ,
    "Assets": {
      "arrayValue": {
        "values": [
          {
            "mapValue": {
              "fields": {
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show that the document you're fetching is definitely the same one in your screenshot.  The code and result you're showing doesn't make any of that clear.  Ideally there is enough information in the question that anyone can use to duplicate the same results.